# How to convert this JS code into modern TypeScript in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am trying to convert this JS code into modern TypeScript for using in Angular 6.

```
function run(interval, frames) {
    var int = 1;

    function func() {
        document.body.id = "b"+int;
        int++;
        if(int === frames) { int = 1; }
    }

    var swap = window.setInterval(func, interval);
}

run(1000, 10); //millisec
```

I did some improvements but it's still not working as expected. How can I completely convert it into TypeScript for working with Angular perfectly?

Comment: Where do you want to put this code? Service, component, or directive?

Comment: Inside the component

Comment: Refer to component architecture once and fit your function in it. https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components

Answer (score 0):

Since TypeScript is a Superset of JavaScript. Every normal JavaScript is completely valid TypeScript.

That being said, here's how you can introduce strong typing and Modern ES6 Syntax:

```
function run(interval: number, frames: number) {
  let int: any = 1;

  function func() {
    document.body.id = "b" + int;
    int++;
    if (int === frames) {
      int = 1;
    }
  }

  const swap = window.setInterval(func, interval);
}

run(1000, 10); //millisec
```

**Note:** I've just added types to arguments of the `run` function. I've also set `int` of type any as you're then adding it to a string and then incrementing it as well. You can check if it's valid or not by pasting it in [**TypeScript Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/). It should give you any errors in there.

Comment: What about function keywords?

Comment: `function` keyword is perfectly valid in TypeScript. You can check if out on TypeScript Playground. Not exactly sure what you're really planning on doing here. Do you want to convert this into a Component?

Answer (score 0):

I'm expanding a bit on SiddAjmera's answer here. I've replaced the `func()` function inside `run` with an anonymous arrow function. I've removed the `any` type (which you should never use).

I have placed the code in an Angular component.

```
class TestAngular {

  int:number
  swap:number

  run(interval: number, frames: number) {

    this.int = 1

    this.swap = window.setInterval(()=>{
        console.log(this.int)
        this.int++
        if (this.int == frames) {
           this.int = 1
        }
    }, interval)

}


let s = new TestAngular()
s.run(500,10)
```